# Lightweight SQL server for Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a lighweight database/SQL-server to run on a Raspberry Pi. Since it should be accessible from more than one application, embedded databases like SQLite would not work, thus it should be a standalone database (I know that SQLite databases can be read by more than one process at the same time, but I'm mostly doing write-operations which would lead to many locks on the file).

From what I found on the web, people seem to advice against using databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL on the Pi for performance reasons. Is there a lightweight database to use on the Pi without slowing down the whole system?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are *not* embedded databases. They are separate servers that you access over the network. AFAIK they do NOT have any version that can be installed on a phone. The articles you found probably talk about connecting to a central database or replicating data between local storage and a central database

Comment: An SQLite database can be accessed from multiple processes. A client/server database is to be accessed over a network.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Of course MySQL and PostgreSQL are not embedded, embedded is not what I want. The Pi is an armhf system with linux, it would not be a problem to install mysql or PostgreSql (it's just apt-get install mysql-server, done). But it would'nt be that good performance-wise.

Comment: @CL As I already wrote, there are mainly write-operations involved. Each process has to lock the whole file while writing, that's my problem with SQLite. A client/server database can of course be acessed on the same machine...

Comment: I think mysql just works fine on my pi. Have you tried it or just read it on the net. And it also depends on what you will use the sql for.

Comment: @Tan Thanks, I will give it a try of course. I was just looking for some hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into this http://www.firebirdsql.org/. It should be lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You're just speculating based on anecdotes, which is the worst way to make decisions.

Build a test case on a Pi, exercise it and collect metrics. You may find that the flash storage of the Pi is sufficiently fast that the write locks aren't a big deal.

Comment: Yes, I would have to do that anyway, you are completely right. But some hints would accelerate this process of testing, maybe there is a database I wasn't aware of etc.

Comment: You haven't given anything in the way of details on the type of data you're handling, the usage intensity in the way of qualified metrics, or what kind of environment this is going to be running in. That makes it extremely hard to make a specific recommendation. Postgres and MariaDB (MySQL) are usually good places to start, and LevelDB and SQLite are good embedded alternatives. Remember, MySQL was developed for systems with a fraction of the CPU power and memory of a Raspberry Pi (~200MHz, 64MB).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)? It has a SQLite-compatible API and a small footprint, it supports concurrency, although it is not a relational database. Here is the [comparison of BDB vs SQLite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/bdb-sqlite-comparison-wp-176431.pdf).

Alternatively you can use [Gadfly](http://gadfly.sourceforge.net/) SQL database for Python.